# Handling form submit with jQuery on Enter

Tags: jquery

I have this very simple form:

```
<form id="header_search"><input type="text" value="search"></form>
```

and this is my jQuery:

```
$("#header_search").keypress(function(e)
{
    e.preventDefault();
    alert("searching :)");

    return false;
});
```

But this function doesn't get triggered on submit by pressing enter.  Any idea what is going wrong?

Thanks!!

Comment: why not bind it with `.submit(function)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `keypress` event on `form`, use `submit` which will work with both `enter` and `submit` button `click`.

```
$(function(){
    $("#header_search").submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        alert("searching :)");
    });
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/usmanhalalit/7f6y8/

Comment: @Usman its not working either, and in both cases for some reason appending ? at the end of the url

Comment: That's the form submitting, either because you're not preventing-default or you've got another error causing the script to stop executing before it gets that far. Check the JS console for any error messages.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add a bind to the keypress. I'm not for certain though.

Comment: what is the handler function? Should it just be "e" ?

Comment: Yep, just do like you usually would just with altered methods: $("#header_search").bind("keypress", function(e) { .....

Comment: @MichaelGrigsby Friend, its not gonna work, `form` has no `keypress` event.

Comment: Also, if this worked, it would submit the form as soon as the user typed the first character...

Comment: hmm, so your saying the Html form has no keypress event? How jQuery works is it dynamically injects the Javascript into whatever element is in the selector. How does it not have a keypress event then? I'm lost lol, I'm still learning jQuery though, so both @GeekedOut and I are learning.